# How to run SSL with mongoose webserver API

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, mongoose-web-server

I use the Mongoose webserver API in C to implement a small HTTP API. It's working fine so far but if I want to use SSL, the server rejects the requests.

To generate the ssl key and certificate, I used the following approach:

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.0-beta2 21 Apr 2009

# openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 1000 -nodes

# cat key.pem > ssl.pem; cat cert.pem >> ssl.pem
```

According to [this](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/docs/SSL.md) manual, mongoose wants the key and cert in one file.

I also set the `NS_ENABLE_SSL` compile flag to enable the ssl part of mongoose.

To initialize mongoose I do the following in my C source:

```
struct mg_server *server;
server = mg_create_server(NULL, ev_handler);
printf("%s",mg_set_option(server, "document_root", "/var/www"));
printf("%s",mg_set_option(server, "listening_port", "80"));
printf("%s",mg_set_option(server, "ssl_certificate", "ssl.pem"));
```

My event handler does nothing but logging the requests on the console at the moment:

```
static int ev_handler(struct mg_connection *conn, enum mg_event ev) {

 switch(ev){
    case MG_AUTH: printf("MG_AUTH event handler called with uri = '%s'\n", conn->uri);
    break;
 case MG_REQUEST:
     printf("MG_REQUEST event handler called with uri = '%s'\n", conn->uri);
     break;
 case MG_POLL:
     printf("MG_POLL event handler called with uri = '%s'\n", conn->uri);
     break;
 case MG_HTTP_ERROR:
     printf("MG_HTTP_ERROR event handler called with uri = '%s'\n", conn->uri);
     break;
 default:
     DBG("MG_CLOSE event handler called with uri = '%s'\n", conn->uri);
     break;
 }
 return MG_FALSE;
}
```

If I try to open a HTML file from the document root in the browser, the server closes the connection without delivering content.

Console output:

```
(null)
(null)
(null)
MG_POLL event handler called with uri = '(null)'
MG_CLOSE event handler called with uri = '(null)'
```

The first three (null) are the return values from the mg_set_option which are `NULL` if no problem occurs while setting an option.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you're using "https://my.ip:80" when connecting to the server. Otherwise, browser is going to use HTTP protocol, and mongoose will reject the connection because it expects SSL handshake, and gets plain HTTP data. I think that is what's going on.
2. You're returning `MG_FALSE` on `MG_AUTH` event, which tells mongoose "connection is not authenticated, close it immediately."

Solution:

- return `MG_TRUE` on `MG_AUTH` event. For other events, returning `MG_FALSE` is fine.
- use listening_port 443, and `https://` when connecting to the server

Comment: Yeah thats it! I tried `https` but I forget to force the port number to 80. Thanks for your help so far. Would it be possible to run SSL beside plain http? There are some use cases where the client isn't able to handle SSL.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "run SSL beside plain http" ? Do you mean two instances, one HTTP another HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I was not sure how the implementation would look like. So is it save to start two instances of the server with using a reference to the same event handler?

Comment: Absolutely, starting two instances with the same event handler is OK. One instance can serve on HTTP port, another on HTTPS port. If only secure connections are allowed, HTTP instance could redirect all requests to the HTTPS instance:


    if (conn->local_port == HTTP_PORT) {
    }